# Android 2.3 emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am trying to debug an issue with my webpage on Android 2.3, Since I don't have that old android device I downloaded Android Studio along with Android SDK.

When I try to create emulator I only get option for 4.4, Can I create android 2.3 emulator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to open the SDK Manager(can be done via Studio or Eclipse) `From Android Studio, select Tools > Android > SDK Manager`. and download the packages and system AVD Images for Android 2.3.x

Comment: Where can I download AVD Images? AVD Manager have only option for create which has target for 4.4

Comment: In the SDK Manager not the AVD Manager. From Android Studio, select Tools > Android > SDK Manager.